# ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 4 for 'in_top_k/InTopKV2' (op: 'InTopKV2') with input shapes: [?,28,28,10], [?], []

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to Tensorflow and I am trying to train on MNIST. However, the code fails on

```
correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, tf.argmax(y, axis=1), 1)
```

with the error "ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 4 for 'in_top_k/InTopKV2' (op: 'InTopKV2') with input shapes: [?,28,28,10], [?], []"

What is going on here, and what do I need to know to make this compatible with different architectures in the future? I've included the entire file below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_io

tf.reset_default_graph()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 28, 28), name='x_input')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 10), name='y_label')
y = tf.stop_gradient(y, name="stop_gradient_y")

input_layer = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1], name='x_reshaped')

fc_layer1 = tf.layers.dense(
        inputs=input_layer, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='fc_layer_1')

fc_layer2 = tf.layers.dense(
        inputs=fc_layer1, units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='fc_layer_2')

fc_layer3 = tf.layers.dense(
        inputs=fc_layer2, units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='fc_layer_3')

fc_layer4 = tf.layers.dense(
        inputs=fc_layer3, units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='fc_layer_4')

fc_layer5 = tf.layers.dense(
        inputs=fc_layer4, units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='fc_layer_5')

logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=fc_layer5, units=10, name='logits')
classes = tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1, name='classes')
probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="probabilities_out")
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits, name='loss_func')
grad = tf.gradients(loss, x)
grad_out = tf.identity(grad, name='gradient_out')

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, tf.argmax(y, axis=1), 1)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train/np.float32(255)
y_train = y_train.astype(np.int32)
x_test = x_test/np.float32(255)
y_test = y_test.astype(np.int32)

y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

num_epochs = 100
batch_size = 100

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print('Epoch: {}'.format(epoch))
        for i in range(x_train.shape[0] // batch_size):
            batch_indices = np.random.randint(x_train.shape[0], size=batch_size)
            x_batch = x_train[batch_indices]
            y_batch = y_train[batch_indices]
            sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={x: x_batch, y: y_batch})
        acc_test = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: x_test, y: y_test})
        print(epoch, "Test accuracy:", acc_test)

    constant_graph = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
            sess, 
            sess.graph.as_graph_def(), 
            ['probabilities_out', 'gradient_out'])

    graph_io.write_graph(constant_graph, '.', 'mnist_gradient_fc_without.pb', as_text=False)
```

Comment: Did you try printing out the shapes of both `logits` and `y`?

Comment: The shapes are (?, 28, 28, 10) for logits and (?, 10) for y. That confuses me, because shouldn't 

logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=fc_layer5, units=10, name='logits')

create the output layer of size (?, 10) rather than (?, 28, 28, 10)?

Comment: I figured it out. My input layer was not what I thought. It was 28x28x1, and was messing up all of the fully connected layers. I changed my input layer to size 784x1, and it fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad was of help, remember to always check your shapes in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JacoSolari and Jarom Allen. For the benefit of community providing complete working code here

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_io

tf.reset_default_graph()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 28, 28), name='x_input')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 10), name='y_label')
y = tf.stop_gradient(y, name="stop_gradient_y")

input_layer = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 784 ], name='x_reshaped')


fc_layer1 = tf.layers.dense(
        inputs=input_layer, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='fc_layer_1')

fc_layer2 = tf.layers.dense(
        inputs=fc_layer1, units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='fc_layer_2')

fc_layer3 = tf.layers.dense(
        inputs=fc_layer2, units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='fc_layer_3')

fc_layer4 = tf.layers.dense(
        inputs=fc_layer3, units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='fc_layer_4')

fc_layer5 = tf.layers.dense(
        inputs=fc_layer4, units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='fc_layer_5')

logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=fc_layer5, units=10, name='logits')
classes = tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1, name='classes')
probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="probabilities_out")
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits, name='loss_func')
grad = tf.gradients(loss, x)
grad_out = tf.identity(grad, name='gradient_out')

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, tf.argmax(y, axis=1), 1)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train/np.float32(255)
y_train = y_train.astype(np.int32)
x_test = x_test/np.float32(255)
y_test = y_test.astype(np.int32)

y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

num_epochs = 5
batch_size = 100

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print('Epoch: {}'.format(epoch))
        for i in range(x_train.shape[0] // batch_size):
            batch_indices = np.random.randint(x_train.shape[0], size=batch_size)
            x_batch = x_train[batch_indices]
            y_batch = y_train[batch_indices]
            sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={x: x_batch, y: y_batch})
        acc_test = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: x_test, y: y_test})
        print(epoch, "Test accuracy:", acc_test)

    constant_graph = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
            sess, 
            sess.graph.as_graph_def(), 
            ['probabilities_out', 'gradient_out'])

    graph_io.write_graph(constant_graph, '.', 'mnist_gradient_fc_without.pb', as_text=False)
```

Output:

```
Epoch: 0
0 Test accuracy: 0.9527
Epoch: 1
1 Test accuracy: 0.9683
Epoch: 2
2 Test accuracy: 0.9731
Epoch: 3
3 Test accuracy: 0.9776
Epoch: 4
4 Test accuracy: 0.9821
INFO:tensorflow:Froze 12 variables.
INFO:tensorflow:Converted 12 variables to const ops.
```